# mysql_ to mysqli_ Conversion Problems

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a small website that I wanted to switch over to the mysqli_* functions, and after [reading](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi) [up a lot](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) on it I decided to do the switch by doing a replace-all `mysql_` with `mysqli_` -- I then went through and verified that everything changed correctly...

Now, the `mysqli_connect()` works - (I get a valid resource connection back from it) but further down the PHP script I have a `mysqli_query` function that is returning `NULL` no matter what I put in as the SQL.

Any thoughts what could be happening?

The relevant code:

```
function connecti_database() {
  mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
}

connecti_database();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table where id = 5';
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
var_dump($result); // this returns NULL every time
```

Comment: +1 for [converting your `mysql_*` functions to `mysqli`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php#answer-12860140).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqli functions require **two** parameters, not one
...and a developer **required to read documentation** first.

```
function connecti_database() {
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
  mysqli_select_db($mysqli,DB_DATABASE);
}

connecti_database();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table where id = 5';
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Comment: hmm... still getting NULL in the var_dump. (To be honest, I did try this exact thing before posting, but stupidly forgot 'global'.)

Comment: boneheaded moment for me - i needed yet another global here. Thanks, it is working now.